# Не срабатывает код проверки всех элементов списка (текстовые поля)

Tags: android, kotlin

Программа вылетает, в логе ошибок нет.

Задача: если все поля не пустые - начинается проверка на корректность даты всех этих полей, если хоть одно поле с ошибкой или есть пустое поле - код выводит `false` и дальше код не исполняется.

```
fun FirstFragment.correctDateAll(): Boolean {
if ((listOfDates.forEach{i -> i.text}).toString().isNotEmpty()) {

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        fun parseLocalDateOrNull(text: Unit, formatter: DateTimeFormatter) = try {
            LocalDate.parse(text.toString(), formatter)
        } catch (ex: DateTimeParseException) {
            null
        }

        val dateFormatInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
        val dateCorrect = parseLocalDateOrNull(listOfDates.forEach{i -> i.text.toString()}, dateFormatInput)

        if (dateCorrect == null) {
                // введена некорректная дата
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Некорректная дата! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return false
        }
        else
        {
            return true
        }
 }
  else
  {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: подробней, какая ошибка? желательно приложить листинг

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста, исправил и дополнил вопрос

Comment: если приложение само закрывается, то ошибка должна быть, просто она может не всегда показываться в логах, требуется несколько раз повторить сценарий падения приложения. Без лога ошибки вам сложно будет помочь.

Comment: могу пока только сказать что дело в `(listOfDates.forEach{i -> i.text})`, так как когда там был не список, а конкретное поле, функция работала. Буду повторять, чтобы отловить ошибку

Comment: `i -> i.text` попробуйте заменить на `i -> if (i == null) "" else i.text` - гадание :)

Comment: так как textView не может быть null сделал так: https://i.postimg.cc/Jh82qQbG/i-2.png , но есть замечание к `""`. Но всё равно вылетает, но кажется виновник нашелся )

Comment: это исправляет ошибку? если да, то скорее всего вы из i получаете null, как мне кажется, другой причины не вижу. Еще возможно не верный формат, если дальше идет форматирование даты. но опять же, без листинга ошибки это просто гадание. Хз ничего не понятно :D

Comment: конечно вы не сможете понять - так как не видите весь код (тут моя недоработка). Внутри этой функции вызывалась функция с "currentView", она и давала ошибку, так как не было никакого текущего поля. Пока убрал её. Вам спасибо за помощь. Надо переделать код. Ошибок по самому коду нет. Но сама функция стала неправильно работать.  Просьба посмотреть - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325576/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-true-%D0%B8-false-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-foreach.