# Не правильно определяется true и false из-за forEach

Tags: android, kotlin

Функция всегда выдает false, даже если введены даты правильно. Как таковых ошибок нет.

Задача: если все поля из списка не пустые - начинается проверка на корректность даты всех этих полей, если хоть одно поле с ошибкой или есть пустое поле - код выводит false и дальше код не исполняется.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun FirstFragment.correctDateAll(): Boolean {
  if ((listOfDates.forEach{i -> i.text}).toString().isNotEmpty()) {

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        fun parseLocalDateOrNull(text: Unit, formatter: DateTimeFormatter) = try {
            LocalDate.parse(text.toString(), formatter)
        } catch (ex: DateTimeParseException) {
            null
        }

        val dateFormatInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
        val dateCorrect = parseLocalDateOrNull(listOfDates.forEach{i -> i.text.toString()},dateFormatInput)

        if (dateCorrect == null) {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Есть некорректная дата! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            return true
        }
}
else
{
    return false
}
```

}

Думаю проблема в

```
val dateCorrect = parseLocalDateOrNull(listOfDates.forEach{i -> i.text.toString()}, dateFormatInput)
```

С массивами (списком) надо наверно не так работать. Может надо динамически создавать переменные по количеству `i` , затем им присваивать значения и проверять...?

Comment: строка `if ((listOfDates.forEach{i -> i.text}).toString().isNotEmpty()) {` не имеет смысла. Что тут вообще должно быть? Описывайте задачу точнее. Не "Не правильно определяется true и false из-за forEach". А что нужно сделать и что нужно получить, какие входные данные и какой результат должен быть

Comment: дополнил, смысл этого - в проверке всех полей из списка. Как таковых ошибок нет, функция выполняется, но не правильно.

Comment: `forEach` ничего не возвращает (а точнее возвращает Unit, его "автоматически" возвращают все функции, которые **явно** не возвращают какого-либо значения), просто для каждого элемента выполняется переданная лямда. Это то же самое, что и `for (i in listOfDates) {}`. Скорей всего вы перепутали с [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) функцией. `text: Unit` тоже бессмыслица. Скорей всего там должен быть String, но даже если принять, что вы перепутали  forEach c map, то результатом map будет `List<String>`, так что тут тоже ничего не понятно

Comment: По поводу Unit https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#unit-returning-functions

Comment: первое 'forEach' вроде как работает, так как код его проходит... Во втором случае я и сам понимаю что это не правильно.... А если из справки по андроид - "С помощью all и предиката можно узнать, выполняется ли условие для всех элементов."  ? и сделать на этой основе что-то. Просто надо "пробежаться" функцией `parseLocalDateOrNull` по всем полям из списка

Comment: можно сделать так для всех полей в списке: '.... val dateCorrect1 = parseLocalDateOrNull(listOfDates[1].text.toString(), dateFormatInput)
            val dateCorrect2 = parseLocalDateOrNull(listOfDates[2].text.toString(), dateFormatInput)
            if (dateCorrect1 == null || dateCorrect2 == null) {.....'    А если бы количество было не известно?